# Change the subnet of an already running Amazon MQ broker

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, amazon-mq

I created an Amazon MQ Broker with ActiveMQ which I just made an error and selected the wrong subnet. The problem is that via the AWS console I can't seem to edit the subnet parameter. It only lets me edit the Security Groups but not the Subnet parameter.

The broker is one instance only.

Is there any way of editing the subnet parameter on an already running broker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the subnet of a running server. That applies to other things like RDS and EC2, not just Amazon MQ.

You have to delete it and recreate it to place it in a different subnet.